# Distributing a network logging Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have a client that wants to conduct an experiment that involves tracking people's browsing habits. All participants in the experiment will agree to share their browsing history with the client, so there's no privacy issue here.

We thought we'd create a Chrome extension that logs what we want and reports to server (we want more than just the URLs).

Placing such an extension on the Chrome Store seems unnatural - only several hundred people will use it (specific people who will participate in the experiment and sign a contract). To all others, this is just Spyware.

Problem is - how do we distribute it? The experiment is limited to several hundred people. Is there any real alternative to the Chrome Store?

Comment: See [Is it possible to create a Chrome Extension for private distribution outside Chrome Web Store?](//stackoverflow.com/a/12460666)

Comment: You can publish unlisted or to a Google Group.